# Copy partial screenshot to Pasteboard

Tags: xcode, uipasteboard

So, the code to copy part of my screen to the pasteboard works because it was successfully coping it to my photo album.  But, I want to be able to paste the partial screenshot into a new SMS message.  I know it will have to be done manually (long hold on message and Paste), but it either pasted nothing, or does not have the Paste option (as it's saving it as a String).  The middle portion of the code is the part I'm struggling with.  Any help would be great.  I've changed the forPasteboardType to "image" but that does not work either.

```
    //Capture part of Screen Shot
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
        CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, 98);    //
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:c];
        UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Send Screenshot to Pasteboard    
    UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:UIPasteboardNameGeneral create:YES];
    pasteBoard.persistent = YES;
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
    [pasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypePNG];     

    /////// Open SMS
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"Hello from me, paste image here -->";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123456789", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
    ////// End SMS
}
```

Comment: So, I removed the middle portion, declared "UIPasteboard *pasteBoard;" in my .h file, Added "pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];" in my ViewDidLoad, and finally put "pasteBoard.image = viewImage;" to send the image to the Pasteboard.  If I open a new SMS manually, I can paste the image.  I also works in a new email.  BUT, when I try to paste it into the newly created SMS within my app, it will not work?  I thought maybe because I had text in the body, so I removed the "controller.body" line and still can't.  I feel I'm close though!

Comment: OK, I got it to work by using this code to just open the native  SMS app,      NSString *stringURL = @"sms:";    
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

Comment: I can now paste the image into the native SMS app.  It still shows a white border on the top from where I cropped it down.  Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Capture part of Screen Shot
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, 98);    //
[self.view.layer renderInContext:c];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Send Screenshot to Pasteboard    
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:UIPasteboardNameGeneral create:YES];
pasteBoard.persistent = YES;
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
[pasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypePNG];     

NSString *stringURL = @"sms:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: When I opened the text message, and found the image is not inside it. I am sure the image is not nil.